# text extract from scanned pdfs

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript, pdftotext

My problem is that I have a bunch of PDF files and I want to convert them to text files. Some of them are pure PDFs while others have scanned pages inside. I am writing a program in python so I am using pdftotext to convert them to TXTs.

I am using the command below

```
filename = glob.glob(src)  //src is my directory with my files 
    for file in filename:
        subprocess.call(["pdftotext", file])
```

What I would like to ask is if there is a way to check for scanned pages before the conversion so that I can use ghostscript commands with pdftotext to manipulate them. 
For now I have a treshold to check the size of the .txt file and if it is below that treshold  I am using ghostscript commands to manipulate them.

The problem is that for big-sized files with 50 or 60 scanned out of 90 pages even with pdftotext the size of the file is always above the treshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'pure' PDF file can have images in it....

There's no easy way to tell whether a PDF file is a scanned page or not. Your best bet, I think, would be to analyse the page content streams to see if they consist of nothing but images (some scanners break up the single scanned page into multiple images). You could assume that they are scanned pages, in any event you won't get any text out of them with Ghostscript.

Another approach would be to use the pdf_info.ps program for Ghostscript and have it list fonts uses. No fonts == no text, though potentially there may be fonts present and still no text. Also I don't think this works on a page by page basis.